# php, trim utf8 encoded string

Tags: php, utf-8

lets say there is an product list page, where product names and descriptions are listed. The description cant be longer than 20 characters. Its very easy to do in php... until I met the utf8 characters

```
here is a text from my native language: női dolog
```

but I cut it at the worst place, the ő character damages:

```
here is a text from my native language: n�
```

how to dodge it? I tried to utf encode and decode it, with less success. Ideas?

Comment: $textToTrim = substr($textToTrim, 0, 20); ----- I hope it helped :)))))))))))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the encoding aware [mb functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php):

```
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
```

For more information, read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`mb*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) extension to work with multibyte strings. You can't use `substr()` for them, because it works with *bytes* and not *symbols* (and they are not same in terms of multibyte encodings). So to trim string till 20 symbols, use [`mb_substr()`](https://www.php.net/mb_substr)

```
$result = mb_substr($data, 0, 20);//add UTF-8 to point utf encoding
```